# Двойная нижняя обводка,а показана одинарная

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

Всем доброго времени суток.
Прописал на сайте стили,двойную обводку снизу,но почему то на сайте именно одинарная.
Заранее благодарю за ответ.
P.S. В корзину добавьте любой товар.
Скрин проблемы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Сам сайт - http://tiarsekj.bget.ru/cart/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, там вопрос в высоте (толщине) линии, дайте ссылку на сайт, тогда точно можно будет сказать, укажите 4px

```
table th, table td {
  border-bottom: 4px double #4169e1;
  padding: 1em;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Каждый раз я себе говорю:-"надо ставить ссылку на видное место"
Но нет,каждый раз я пихаю ее в самый конец:D
Так что ссылка есть,просто она не заметна.
А так помогло,не знаю,как я до такого не догадался.
Благодарю :)